# What is causing excel to crash after updating file thru java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have some java code that opens an excel sheet, adds auto filter to a group of columns, then saves and closes. The problem is that when a user opens the file and trys to sort smallest to largest or largest to smallest excel will freeze then crash. But if you first filter then you can sort with out issue and it does not freeze and crash.

```
private static void AddFilter()
{
    //Adds filter to the rows in Column 2
    try 
    {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\gria\\Desktop\\Fleet Manager Summary.xls");

        HSSFWorkbook report = new HSSFWorkbook(fileIn);

        Sheet sheet  = report.getSheetAt(0);
        sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A5:P5"));


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\gria\\Desktop\\Fleet Manager SummaryT.xls");
        report.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you,

**UPDATE:**
After some experimenting I have updated the info and code since the original question was asked to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(report);
```

to

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(report);
```

XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells() works for XSSfWorkbook, but not for the HSSFWorkbook.

[Documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateAllFormulaCells(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook))

Also,
you can edit your commented code to:

```
for(int i = 5; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) 
{
    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(6);

    //I don't know if you have data in all of the cells,
    //So I suggest you to evaluate null
    if(cell != null && !cell.getStringCellValue().isEmpty())
    {
        cell.setCellValue(Double.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue()).doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, tell me which version of POI are you using.

Comment: I am using version 3.15. After a lot of experimenting I have found out that my question wasn't 100% accurate. I am updating it now.

Comment: I was using 3.13, after I upgraded to 3.15 my code which was fine with 3.13, broke. So I reverted to 3.13. And also when I am using poi library version 3.13 with poi-ooxml library version 3.14, I had some issues. When I am using both poi and poi-ooxml libs with 3.13 version, I have no issues. But why are you invoking XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells() method on HSSFWorkbook?

Comment: I had some equations that were updating before I found that the excel type was changing from XLSX to XLS and I forgot to remove it. I will remove it from my post to avoid futher confusion. I will try going to the 3.13 version and see if that works. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: I have downloaded the 3.13 version and referenced it instead of 3.15 but I am still receiving the same issue. I have also fully updated the original question to remove some confusion after some more experimenting. Thank you for all your help btw